# How do I use an old GPG key when I switch machines or work on different platforms?

Tags: git, pgp, gnupg

I currently have "signing Git commits with GPG keys" as part of my workflow.

I'm wondering how I can use my old signature on new computers or OSes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using GnuPG, you can easily export your secret keys using

```
gpg -a --export-secret-keys [key-id] >key.asc
```

and subsequently import them on another computer (`gpg --import key.asc`).

Especially for signing work, [using multiple subkeys for multiple machines](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31594/what-is-a-good-general-purpose-gnupg-key-setup/31598#31598) is recommended. If one of the computers is compromised, you can easily revoke a subkey without losing certifications.